# Создание таблиц в Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь создать таблицы в Oracle 10g. Таблица IZGOTOVITEL связана с таблицей FILIALS связью один ко многому. Остальные таблицы соединены между собой связью многие ко многим, которая разрешается с помощью дополнительных таблиц: IZGOTOVITEL_GOODS, BUYER_GOODS, BUYER_REMONT

```
CREATE TABLE IZGOTOVITEL (
Idcompany int PRIMARY KEY,
Company varchar(40) NOT NULL,
INNcompany varchar(10) NULL,
AdddressComp varchar(60) NOT NULL,
PhoneCompany varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE FILIALS (
Idfilial int PRIMARY KEY,
Filial varchar(20) NOT NULL,
InnFilial varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Chief varchar(60) NOT NULL,
Capacity number(3) NOT NULL,
Address varchar(60) NOT NULL,
Phone varchar(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(Idcompany) REFERENCES IZGOTOVITEL
);


CREATE TABLE GOODS (
Idgoods int PRIMARY KEY,
Goods varchar(40) NOT NULL,
Categoty varchar(20) NULL,
Country varchar(20) NOT NULL,
DateStart date NOT NULL,
Period number(4) NOT NULL,
DateBuy date NOT NULL,
Cost numeric(15, 2) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE IZGOTOVITEL_GOODS( 
izg_id int, 
goods_id int, 
CONSTRAINT pk_izgotovitel_goods PRIMARY KEY (izg_id, goods_id), 
CONSTRAINT fk_izg_id FOREIGN KEY (izg_id) REFERENCES IZGOTOVITEL (Idcompany), 
CONSTRAINT fk_goods_id FOREIGN KEY (goods_id) REFERENCES GOODS (Idgoods)
);

CREATE TABLE BUYER (
CustomerID number(5) PRIMARY KEY,
Customer varchar(60) NOT NULL,
AddressCust varchar(60) NOT NULL,
Sign BLOB NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE BUYER_GOODS( 
buye_id number, 
good_id int, 
CONSTRAINT pk_buye_good PRIMARY KEY (buye_id, good_id), 
CONSTRAINT fk_buye_id FOREIGN KEY (buye_id) REFERENCES BUYER (CustomerID), 
CONSTRAINT fk_good_id FOREIGN KEY (good_id) REFERENCES GOODS (Idgoods)
);


CREATE TABLE REMONT (
Idremont int PRIMARY KEY,
CostRepair numeric(15, 2) NOT NULL,
RemontName varchar(60) NOT NULL,
StartDate date NOT NULL,
StopDate date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE BUYER_REMONT( 
buyer_id number, 
remont_id int, 
CONSTRAINT pk_buyer_remont PRIMARY KEY (buyer_id, remont_id), 
CONSTRAINT fk_buyer_id FOREIGN KEY (buyer_id) REFERENCES BUYER (CustomerID), 
CONSTRAINT fk_remont_id FOREIGN KEY (remont_id) REFERENCES REMONT (Idremont)
);
```

В итоге какие-то таблицы создались. А в каких-то есть ошибки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите в чём моя ошибка, что я делаю не так?

Comment: foreign key это ссылка существующей колонки (а колонки Idcompany у вас в FILIALS нет) на первичный ключ другой таблицы (и первичного ключа у вас так же нет)

Comment: И кстати странно, у вас правильный синтаксис создания foreign скажем в BUYER_GOODS но совершенно порезанный, не корректный в FILIALS.

Answer (score 0):

Первая ошибка - несоблюдение синтаксиса. FK ссылается на индекс, а не на таблицу.

Вторая - ровно то, что написано, объект с таким именем уже существует, посему таблицу создать нельзя.

Третья ошибка - следствие второй.